# How to wrap text on a 100% width div?

Tags: html, css

I have a 3 div with their display property set to table-cell.  Div 1 is fixed width (22px).  Div 2 needs to take up the rest of the available space.  Div 3 needs to be pinned to the right side and only take up as much as the text that is in it.

So the issue I am having is when the contents of Div 2 are too big it pushes Div 3 off the screen.

[image: None clipped text]

[image: Bold totals pushed off the screen]

This is a mobile web application.  Ideally what would happen is the text in Div 2 would clip if it was going to push the bold totals of the screen.  I could do it in javascript, but don't think I should have to.

Here is the template code for the list item:

```
<div class="liContainer">
    <div class="cell a"><img src="badge.png" width="20px"/></div>
    <div class="cell b">{title}</div>
   <div class="cell c"><b>{total}</b></div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.cell{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.a{
    width: 22px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.b{
    width: 100%;
}

.c{
    text-align: right;
}

.liContainer{
    width: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}
```

**EDIT:  The result of employing the technique Jithesh describes below**
[image]

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word;` could do the trick for you

Comment: Your `width` values don't sum up to `100%`, that is almost always a way to shoot yourself in the food. Other than that, have you tried `.b { overflow: hidden;}`? (after fixing the width).

Comment: I put your entire code into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marconius/vPHYC/) and it actually seems to work fine for me as it is. Are you sure you're not setting something other than what you put down here?

Comment: tried both of those ideas.  Neither worked.  As for the values not adding up to 100%, i'm not really sure how to address that.  I don't want to assign percentages to div a or c.

Comment: what about assign a max-width to .b ? less than 100%

Comment: is just for mobile? why u don't set a container for your width display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with floats and it works perfect.

- Give float(left or right) to the elements that has fixed width or width of its contents.
- And `overflow: hidden` to the element that should take up the remaining width.

**Important:** The cells have to be in the order a > c > b as the floating cells must preceed the div that takes up the remaining space.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="liContainer">
    <div class="a cell"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width="20px"/></div>
    <div class="c cell"><b>197</b></div>
    <div class="b cell">Hey, This is the long long long title</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.cell{
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

.a{
    width: 22px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
}

.b{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.c{
    float: right;
    background: #ccc;
}

.liContainer{
    width: 100%;
    //display: table-row;
}
```

**More improvements**

Add `text-overflow: ellipsis` and `white-space: nowrap;` to the block 'c' to clip the overflowing text with '...' that looks cool than normal clipping.

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3JEr/

Comment: Nailed it.  awesome.  Taught me some new concepts I'd never utilized.  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

just add this :

```
max-width:100%
```

Answer (score 0):

What can be done is that if the `b.` is going to be too big, it will wrap the text to the second "row" (the height of whole section would double if needed). For this you have to set up something else than `width: 100%` for the `.b` container.

Why don't you just set `width` of an `.a` to 10%, `.b` to 80% and `.c` to 10%? If you won't define the height the content of a `.b` will just jump into second row.

---

Alternatively, if you need right div to be pinned to the right part of the screen, set absolute position for him like this

```
.c {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

But be carefull, the `.liContainer` should have

```
position: relative;
```

otherwise, the absolute positioning for `.c` won't work.

This won't solve the whole problem probably, you will still need to make `.b` div less than 100% I guess.